# Meteor Upsert not adding to existing value

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Ok I have the upsert function working as intended, with the following issue.  I can't seem to get it to update the existing quantity if the record exists.  I looked through the mongo docs and it says to use the $inc function, but nothing.
Please have a look and see what's wrong.  I've tried putting the {$inc: } in brackets but it still won't work.

Thank you in advance.

```
 Stock.upsert(
                ProductType,

            {
                // Modifier
                $set: {
                    ProductType: ProductType,
                    ProductScent: ProductScent,
                    ProductName: ProductName,
                $inc: {ProductQTY: ProductQTY}


            }}
        );
```

Comment: Could you please try: `Stock.upsert({"ProductType": ProductType}, {$set: {"ProductType": ProductType, "ProductScent": ProductScent, "ProductName": ProductName}}, {$inc: {"ProductQTY": ProductQTY}});`?

Comment: nope won't add anything or update existing now :-(

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in your console?

Comment: Nope, console is clear.

Answer (score 1):

The first argument is a *mongo selector*. That means, that you are searching for a document with the `_id` of `ProductType`. Also your modifier is a bit off. So what what you want to do is something like this:

```
Stock.upsert(
  {
    ProductType: ProductType,
    ProductScent: ProductScent,
    ProductName: ProductName,
  },
  {
    // Modifier
    $set: {
      ProductType: ProductType,
      ProductScent: ProductScent,
      ProductName: ProductName,
    },
    $inc: {ProductQTY: ProductQTY}
  }
);
```

Comment: I just re-read your first reply.  I think I know the issue.  the ProductType is not unique.  There is the usual generated ID that is unique.  Two fields together form the unique value I'm searching for.  There are multiple combinations of product type and like 50 different scent types.  I'm wondering if I need to create a better type of unique id.

Comment: Not necessarily. I updated my answer to query for documents in which all values match.

Comment: Tried the code and still nothing.  I'm stumped now.   Might have to go another way to increment that field.

Comment: I tested the code replacing the values with literals and it _works on my machine_. Check that all the variables are defined. [Proof](https://imgur.com/gallery/EF6ZxHs/new)

Comment: I'm going back over my code to see if I screwed something up.  Very odd.  even if I change them to numbers instead of variables they still won't add up.  Thanks for all your help though, very much appreciated!